# Changing wireless network adapter wireless mode properties

Tags: c#, wireless, device-manager

My school uses 802.11a, but at home I use 802.11b. 
This means every time I go from home to school or the other way I have to go to device manager -> Network adapters -> Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN -> properties -> advanced -> wireless mode -> change the value.

I would like to make a small c# program that does this for me, but I don't know where to start.

Can someone point me in the right direction, I have no idea on where to get started.

I have received an answer from MSDN - but I have not tested it yet.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3a8a096d-b0e8-488c-930f-12735e5f7b4b

**SOLUTION**
After working with this a bit, I found a solution. 
First i used [Process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to figure out which registry values were changed, when I changed the wireless mode manually.

Now changing the value contains 2 steps.
The name for the wireless modes are mapped to a number. The numbers are then mapped in a different registry key to a wireless mode number.
So first I found the number based on the name, and then I set the value in a different registry key.

After that the Network adapter has to be reset, which I used WMI to do.

I got help in  [This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3a8a096d-b0e8-488c-930f-12735e5f7b4b) on MSDN.

I am not sure, if it works across all windows OS, and I am not sure if it works across all network adapters. Anyways, this is what I did.

Comment: Can you post on what is the value that needs to be changed to?

Comment: I have to switch between the following values: 1. 802.11a to 6. 802.11a/b/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION After working with this a bit, I found a solution. First i used Process monitor to figure out which registry values were changed, when I changed the wireless mode manually.

Now changing the value contains 2 steps. The name for the wireless modes are mapped to a number. The numbers are then mapped in a different registry key to a wireless mode number. So first I found the number based on the name, and then I set the value in a different registry key.

After that the Network adapter has to be reset, which I used WMI to do.

I got help in This thread on MSDN.

I am not sure, if it works across all windows OS, and I am not sure if it works across all network adapters. Anyways, this is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

you want to dig into System.Management namespace to mess with devices http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx

Comment: I've looked into it, but I can't find the property I am looking for. I've tried the following:
Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter
Select * from Win32_NetworkClient
Select * from Win32_NetworkConnection
Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
   Select * from Win32_NetworkProtocol

Comment: On second thought, it might aswell be possible you have to "talk" to your adapter's driver instead of asking Windows to accomplish this task ... As a matter of fact, Windows doesn't know how devices work,  drivers do (that's why Windows needs them ^^). Unfortunately I can't know for sure b/c I never tried this kind of things :(

Comment: I have not yet solved the problem, but you gave me a hint on where to look, which is the answer for the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a API written to access all wifi network adapters. You can find its source code at [here](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/). Hope that should get you started.

Comment: I've looked into that, and it seems like the native wifi API is more about network connections and not so much hardware